# Deploying React project to Firebase leads to window that says "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete"

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I have followed all of the steps to initialize my project, I run `npm run build` then I run `firebase deploy` and my the URL it gives me leads me to a default firebase webpage that says "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete"

Thanks for the help!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Walkthrough**

Before starting with anything make sure you have created your project in FireBase & you have used the same Firebase Config in your `firebase.js` file in your local react project folder
[image: Firebase]

1. Create a build folder using:

   **npm run build**

[image: Created build folder in react.js]

[image: build folder hierarchy]

This in turn will create a build folder in the root of your project folder.
Basically the build files are optimized for production, where there are no ongoing changes in code every now & then.

2. Install the Firebase CLI Tools using:

   **npm install -g firebase-tools**

`-g` flag is used here to install it globally, so it can be accessed easily from any project.

3. Sign in & initialize

   **firebase login**

For logging in, you will be redirected to browser window, there you simply have to login using your FireBase credentials.

[image: Firebase initialisation]

```
firebase init
```

You will be asked loads & loads of questions while in `firebase init` but don't worry, I will guide you here:

Are you ready to proceed?

Type `y`, since we want to continue.

Which Firebase features do you want to set up for this directory? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices.

Here, you need to select all features which you included in your project, it may be, you needed nothing & you are just using it for free Hosting. :) In my case, I used Firestore & Storage both in my project & also needed Hosting so, I'm selecting these 3 using space & then press enter.

[image: Correct option set]

Make sure to choose the Firebase Hosting, where Github actions are optional.(Refer green stars on above picture).

When prompted for Firebase rules and other similar stuff, then go with default options.

[image: Firebase rules]

For choosing public directory, make sure you choose the **build** folder

[image: Choose build folder in firebase reactjs]

Go with these options. Make sure you don't overwrite **buid/index.html**.

[image: Initialization of firebase completed]

4. Deploying our web app

   **firebase deploy**

[image: Deploy completed]

That's it we're done

Link for the Deployed application will be in the Terminal

[image: Deployed url]